# How to maintain dependent tables with SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

After adding 'Tasks' and 'TaskDependency' tables to an existing schema I am hitting a wall with maintainability/referential integrity.

My Tables are as follows:

```
Schedule

ScheduleID  Frequency   FrequencyDatePart   StartHour   EndHour DaysOfWeek
1   1   DAY 6   20  1111111

JobTrigger

JobID   JobName NextRun ScheduleID
1   Job1    2013-09-13 16:00:43.350 1

Tasks

TaskID  TaskName    JobID
1   Task1   1
2   Task2   1
3   Task3   1
4   Task4   1

TaskDependency

TaskID  DependsOn
2   1
3   1
4   2
4   3
```

- TaskDependency table will be used to show what tasks are dependent on other tasks.

My questions are:

1. I want to set TaskID and DependsOn as a composite key (or add a
   unique constraint) to prevent duplication.  How could I achieve this
   without adding the DependsOn column to the Tasks table?
2. There is a UI that will manage this functionality, as a JobTrigger is
   modified, what is the most maintainable course of action to
   add/remove tasks from the Tasks table?

My initial thought would be to dump all the associated tasks then re-add them.  This approach feels messy and I would worry as the table grows.

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple foreign keys in a single table pointing at a single field in the parent table, so there's no reason you couldn't have:

```
table TaskDependency:
       TaskID int foreign key -> Tasks.id
       DependsOn int foreign key -> Tasks.id
       UNIQUE KEY (TaskId, DependsOn)
```

This is perfectly acceptable practice.

Answer (score 0):

**Q1**

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX UX_TaskDependency ON (TaskId, Dependency)
GO
```

**Q2**

You can use after trigger on JobTrigger table in order to manage your tasks and add or remove task to your table.